# Steam coming from driver side around the belt

Tags: honda

Car overheats and I drove it around the neighborhood and when I came back and turned it off steam came from the belt area yes they are all tight the guy I bought it from said it needed a thermostat and a temp sensor? Could this be the problem

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Can you give us any more information about the car itself? What is the year/model/engine? Where *exactly* is the steam coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Identify the component that is creating the steam before replacing random components. Stuck shut thermostat would overheat but you have a leak of pressure.
Could be water pump, hose etc. Check first, then replace
Why didnt previous owner replace these components?